# OpenSSH v8 client talking to OpenSSH v6.7p1 server: "no mutual signature algorithm" because of disabled ssh-rsa? But why and how?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, openssh

My server recently stopped offering me public key-based authentication. I tried to log in using my RSA public key and only got:

```
$ ssh -v <server>
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 33: Applying options for <server>
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <server> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <server>:22 as 'user'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:tKraF30I02/eujsuOeMD9Aihjxp/9CXl/lu3c3vGcGs
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[<server>]:22' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/other_key RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/other_key RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> agent
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> explicit
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@<server>'s password:
```

The crucial part seems to be the third-to-last line:

```
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
```

At first I thought it must have something to do with the fact that ssh-rsa has been [deprecated](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2) and finally [disabled by default](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8). However, it turns out the server is quite old, running OpenSSH 6.7p1.

Maybe it is for this reason that the server doesn't tell me which algorithms it supports – modern OpenSSH versions seem to send an [`SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO` with `kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=…`](https://superuser.com/questions/1556852/how-to-check-if-your-ssh-keys-are-in-the-ssh-rsa2-format).

So I had a look at the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but it looks fine and doesn't mention anything related to `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` (= `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` in more recent versions of OpenSSH):

```
…
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,umac-128@openssh.com
…
```

I also tried using `ssh -Q (sig|PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes) <server>` to query the supported signature algorithms but, contrary to what the man page suggests (`ssh … [-Q query_option] … destination`), it seems this queries the *client*(?), not the server as it is the same for every server I've tried.

Then I thought: Wait, but if the server hasn't seen an update in recent times, anyway, it must be my client!

And indeed: `ssh -o "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa" -v <server>` works!

```
$ ssh -o "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=ssh-rsa" -v <server>
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 33: Applying options for <server>
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <server> [<ip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to <server>:22 as 'user'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:tKraF30I02/eujsuOeMD9Aihjxp/9CXl/lu3c3vGcGs
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[<server>]:22' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/other_key RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/other_key RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> explicit
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

How is this possible? Even if my OpenSSH client (v8.9, see above) had deprecated/disabled usage of ssh-rsa with SHA1[0]: As one can see, server & client agree to use SHA256 – which should be perfectly fine?!

What's more, `ssh -Q PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms` does list ssh-rsa:

```
$ ssh -Q PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms
ssh-ed25519
ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com
sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-rsa
rsa-sha2-256
rsa-sha2-512
ssh-dss
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com
rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com
ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com
ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com
sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com
```

I also haven't been able to find a line disabling ssh-rsa (e.g. `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=-ssh-rsa`) anywhere on my computer, whether in `~/.ssh/config`, `/etc/ssh` or anywhere else.

**Concluding:** This is a real mystery to me. Why is ssh-rsa no longer working? (I should mention, ssh-ed25519 public keys work perfectly fine.)

For now I'll just configure `PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa` in my local `~/.ssh/config` but this feels like a dirty workaround for a problem that I haven't understood.

--

**Related posts** of other people having the exact same problem: The server runs OpenSSH v6.7p1, the client is some OpenSSH version > 8 and ssh-rsa authentication fails:

[Suddenly, my ssh requires a password--debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm](https://superuser.com/questions/1753939/suddenly-my-ssh-requires-a-password-debug1-send-pubkey-test-no-mutual-signat)

https://serverfault.com/questions/1064247/ssh-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: The man page says `ssh -Q` queries `ssh` which is the client program (not the server), but doesn't say it lists all _implemented_ algos of a type not the subset _enabled by default_.  And yes when the log says `offering key ... RSA SHA256:fingerprint` that means the _fingerprint_ (computed locally only) used SHA256, not the signature (or probe) sent to the server (and rsa-sha2 signatures sent to versions below 7.2 do fail)

Answer (score 8):

I'm starting to think the reason is [this one](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8):

> OpenSSH has supported RFC8332 RSA/SHA-256/512 signatures since release 7.2 and existing ssh-rsa keys will automatically use the stronger algorithm where possible.

So it seems OpenSSH v6.7p1 doesn't support SHA-256/512 yet and still wants to use SHA1 when confronted with an ssh-rsa key. In particular, the debug output (in the successful case)

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:<fingerprint> explicit
```

was misleading and says nothing about which hashing algorithm was used in the client<>server communication.

Moreover, the [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8332#section-3.2) explains why my server didn't send `server-sig-algs`:

```
Servers that accept rsa-sha2-* signatures for client authentication
SHOULD implement the extension negotiation mechanism defined in
[RFC8308], including especially the "server-sig-algs" extension.
```

All in all, having successfully wasted an entire night on this, I'm flabbergasted by how it didn't occur to the OpenSSH developers that using `ssh-rsa` to mean "use RSA key", "use RSA + SHA1" or "use RSA + any SHA version" (depending on the situation) could be confusing. The RFC at least [is very explicit](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8332#section-3.2).